# The [super mouseDown] blocks keyDown event

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview, keydown

I have an NSTableView where a custom view class is used to populate the rows. The view subclass is overwriting the `mouseDown:` and `keyDown:` event.

The issue is when `mouseDown:` is implementing `[super mouseDown:theEvent];` the `keyDown:` event is not firing and if I leave out the call to super, the drag'n'drop functionality is not firing.

As it is now I can either have keyDown or drag'n'drop. Not both. Are there anyway around this?

Comment: for me it is the other way around actually: when [super mouseDown:theEvent] is being called, keyDown events will fire. This is really weird because I have no ideea how this works or how it makes a difference for the key events system.